# window.location.reload(); is not working in ajax in IE

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, joomla2.5

```
jQuery.ajax(this.action, {
        data: jQuery(":text", this).serializeArray(),
        files: jQuery(":file", this),
        iframe: true,
        processData: false
    }).complete(function(data) {
           document.getElementById('jform_profile_Photo').value=data;//alert('Hiiiii')
           //document.getElementById('fields-container').innerHTML= 'Image changed !';
          window.location.reload();
    });
```

Hi, I am using ajax function to upload a profile picture. In firefox and google chrome after uploading the profile picture, the page is loading automatically and the new profile picture is visible, but in IE, even the page is loading the profile picture is not updating, if we refresh the page once again then the profile picture is coming.

Comment: if i does'nt use any reload function, working fine in firefox and google chrome, but not in IE. If I use any reload functions like window.location.reload(); or window.location.reload(true);

Answer (score 1):

try `window.location=window.location`

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

it should do the trick as it forces a "hard" reload

Answer (score 0):

try this - [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) and this - [How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067/en)